# A story about a kid who befriends an AI and communicates with via pocket calculator?

Tags: story-identification

I read this sometime in the mid-80s.  I don't think it was more than 100 pages or so.

A boy somehow comes in contact with an Artificial Intelligence who lives in a larger mainframe computer, I think via dialing in from a computer at home.  The AI shows him how to modify a pocket calculator so they can communicate while the kid travels around his town.  The boy lives in or near a farm town.  He discovers that a big company owned factory orchard is poisoning the town's water supply with some kind of insecticide run-off, and the Artificial intelligence helps solve this mystery and uncover the crooks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author: Ian McMahan
The Microkid Mystery Series

http://www.amazon.com/Ian-McMahan/e/B001IODQW6/ref=dp_byline_cont_book_1

Comment: Please elaborate on how the answer matches the OP's criteria.

Comment: Wow, I think "Lake Fear" is it, Ben.  Now, I just need to get my hands on a copy.  Thanks.